# Adding transform to an image blurs it in Chrome

Tags: html, image, css, google-chrome, transform

I have an image with a transform applied to it to :transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

Only in Chrome this causes the image to be blurry.

I've tried different proposed solutions such as setting translateZ(0); filter: blur(0) without any success.

Removing the transform property removes the blurry effect.

Here is the current css for the image : 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;

And it looks like this : [image]

And here is the actual image returned from my image service :

[image]

Notice that the first image has blurred edges and the original image does not.

Comment: Did you try ditching the backface and doing a reset on your Z and scale? Like `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;-webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);` ....oh and no need for height/width:auto unless you're overriding inheritance since those are the default values anyway for those properties. Sweet image by the way.

Comment: I did try that but no difference :(

Comment: You can post the code HTML/CSS?

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56143014/2746447