# Blurry text because translate(-50%, -50%) positions on half a pixel

Tags: css, text, translate, blurry

I was having trouble with transform: translate(-50%, -50%) in combination with a google font in chrome. This combination made the text look blurry. I noticed it was caused by the translate and after looking at the position of the element, I noticed it was positioned on half a pixel. I was able to fix it with translate(calc(-50% - 0.5px), -50%), but rather have a better solution than this workaround.

Is there perhaps a way to round the pixels to a whole number when using percentages?

Comment: Are you trying on localhost?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56143014/2746447

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting `transform-style: preserve-3d` on the parent or maybe modify your transform property to also include `perspective(1px)`.